# Manage meeting bookings for a secondary calendar

Tags: exchange, outlook-2010, calendar

What I want to achieve is that one of the employees should be able to manage a shared calendar. It should be possible for her send meeting requests to the staff and when they replies she should receive the responses.

I have created a new calendar, shared it with the staff and when I create a meeting request and send it to an employee I get the following message:

```
This meeting is not in the Calendar folder for this account. Response to this meeting will not be tailed.
```

I searched for this error message and found out that it's by design and that it should not be possible to create meetings from other than your primary calendar.

However, this *should* be possible to do. Our last project manager did exactly this and the new project manager can still use this calendar, but it's tied to our last manager's e-mail (answers are sent to the last manager's mailbox and are sent out in her name). So in some way this should be possible to do.

What we want is either to transfer this calendar to our new project manager (this would be the best) or to create a new calender that works this way.

How do we do this?

Comment: Lots of vital information missing from your question unfortunately.
You haven't said the version of Exchange involved, nor how you have created the new Shared Calendar. It could be a public folder, a shared or resource mailbox, a calendar folder in an existing mailbox etc. You also haven't said what permissions you have applied to the calendar.

Comment: Sorry! We recently changed to Office 365 but still run Outlook 2010 on our machines. I created the calendar by right clicking on my primary calendar and choose "new calendar". After that I shared the calendar to my workmates (I suppose that means it's a calendar folder in an existing mailbox?). Regarding the permissions I tried everything from full permission to limited - same thing.

Comment: There is your problem - you have put the calendar in to an existing mailbox. As you found, that doesn't work properly and is by design. 

Create a resource mailbox instead, grant the permissions on that mailbox calendar. A resource mailbox shouldn't use another licence on Office365.